# Can I Permanently Delete This File from Trash with Terminal?

Tags: terminal, trash

I was trying to add sound file options for the native Messages app on my rMBP with El Capitan. I disabled "System Integrity Protection" (SIP), dragged in the new file, enabled SIP (with all the correct rebooting, as necessary).

I want to delete the file I added now. I was able to move it to the Trash, but it will not delete.

Rather than going through Restarting, choosing Recovery Mode, disabling SIP, restarting, deleting the file, restarting, choosing Recovery Mode, enabling SIP, and restarting, can I just input the following into Terminal?

```
sudo rm /Users/tmhahn/.Trash/Mailtone12.aiff
```

I'm just learning Terminal, so I wanted to ask before I attempted it.

(I know to be careful with "sudo" AND with "rm," which is why I'm confirming this is okay!)

**If using the Terminal in this way is not advisable, do you have another suggestion?**

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This should be fine, I have not faced any issues in doing so in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current command is correct and will work.